# Facebook Audience Network (FBAudienceNetwork.framework) causing Errors

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ios7, xcode6

```
"_CMTimeCompare", referenced from:
  ___24-[FBMediaView loadVideo]_block_invoke in FBAudienceNetwork(FBMediaView.o)



"_CMTimeGetSeconds", referenced from:
       ___24-[FBMediaView loadVideo]_block_invoke111 in FBAudienceNetwork(FBMediaView.o)
       -[FBAdVideoView checkIfVideoEnded] in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdVideoView.o)
       ___84-[FBAdVideoView playMovieWithURL:withVideoPlayCheck:withVideoTimeCheck:withFailure:]_block_invoke
 in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdVideoView.o)
       ___84-[FBAdVideoView playMovieWithURL:withVideoPlayCheck:withVideoTimeCheck:withFailure:]_block_invoke_2
 in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdVideoView.o)
       -[FBAdVideoView updateMaximumWatched:] in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdVideoView.o)   "_CMTimeMake", referenced from:
       -[FBAdVideoView addTimingObserver:] in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdVideoView.o)   "_CMTimeMakeWithSeconds",
 referenced from:
       ___24-[FBMediaView loadVideo]_block_invoke in FBAudienceNetwork(FBMediaView.o)
       -[FBAdVideoView videoScrubberChanged:] in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdVideoView.o)   "_kCMTimeZero", referenced from:
       -[FBAdVideoView checkIfVideoEnded] in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdVideoView.o)
       -[FBAdVideoView playMovieWithURL:withVideoPlayCheck:withVideoTimeCheck:withFailure:]
 in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdVideoView.o)
       ___84-[FBAdVideoView playMovieWithURL:withVideoPlayCheck:withVideoTimeCheck:withFailure:]_block_invoke in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdVideoView.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Swift, try adding "`import CoreMedia`" to the top of any file referencing your FBAudienceNetwork API's, and if you're using Objective C, use "`#import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h>`" (and include the CoreMedia framework in your project).

Comment: Thanks for Replying.. but after adding CoreMedia framework it still gives an error as below-
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)